# Wirtinger derivatives and conjugate

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, several-complex-variables

I haven't found anywhere in the literature (that's available to me, at least) a proper explanation of the following relations for a function $f \in \mathcal{C}(\Omega)$,  $\Omega$ domain of $\mathbb{C}^n$ $$\frac{\overline{\partial f}}{\partial{z_i}} = \frac{\partial \overline{f}}{\partial\overline{z}_{i}}$$
$$ \frac{\overline{\partial f}}{\partial\overline{z}_{i}} = \frac{\partial \overline{f}}{\partial z_{i}}$$
Why are they (must they be) true?

Comment: You may find [this](http://wcherry.math.unt.edu/math5410/wirtinger.pdf) useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid indices, work with one complex variable $z$. Write down the definition of Wirtinger derivatives: 
$$
f_z = \frac12(f_x-if_y),\qquad f_{\bar z} = \frac12(f_x+if_y)
\tag1$$ 
Apply complex conjugate to (1), observing by the way that $\overline{f_x}=(\bar f)_x$, etc.
$$
\overline{f_z} = \frac12(\bar f_x+i\bar f_y),\qquad \overline{f_{\bar z}} = \frac12(\bar f_x-i\bar f_y)
\tag2$$ 
In Wirtinger notation, (2) takes the form
$$
\overline{f_z} = (\bar f)_{\bar z},\qquad \overline{f_{\bar z}} = (\bar f)_z
\tag3$$ 
as claimed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For future reference to anyone having the same doubts, I found something quite informative as to why it must be so in this thread
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/92624/why-partial-and-bar-partial-defined-in-that-way-the-wirtinger-derivativ